# NSUserDefaults in Phonegap

Tags: iphone, xcode, cordova, nsuserdefaults

(I'm an native iPhone developer - new to Phonegap/Cordova)

For certain settings or preferences, we use NSUserDefaults in native iOS. Is there an equivalent when using webviews and phonegap?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can write a plugin to connect them together.

Comment: Is there no storage in the device(connected to phonegap) that persists across app launches and terminations? Seriously?? How to store settings then?

Comment: I'm not sure, check the documentation, or write your own plugin. That's the most I can tell you (since I haven't looked at the documentation, nor write the plugin - I'm only sure about how it works internally).

Comment: @Thiba Phonegap re-implements `window.localStorage` which `NSWebView` attempts to disable. That's the HTML5 way of preserving data across launches. But `NSUserDefaults` is more than that, and a plugin to adapt it to PhoneGap would be separately useful.

Answer (score 1):

There is an [Application preferences Cordova plugin](https://github.com/apla/me.apla.cordova.app-preferences).

[Usage](https://github.com/apla/me.apla.cordova.app-preferences#synopsis):

```
function ok (value) {}
function fail (error) {}

var prefs = plugins.appPreferences;

// cordova interface

// store key => value pair
prefs.store (ok, fail, 'key', 'value');

// store key => value pair in dict (see notes)
prefs.store (ok, fail, 'dict', 'key', 'value');

// fetch value by key (value will be delivered through "ok" callback)
prefs.fetch (ok, fail, 'key');

// fetch value by key from dict (see notes)
prefs.fetch (ok, fail, 'dict', 'key');

// remove value by key
prefs.remove (ok, fail, 'key');

// show application preferences
prefs.show (ok, fail);

// instead of cordova interface you can use promise interface
// you'll receive promise when you won't pass function reference
// as first and second parameter

// fetch the value for a key using promise
prefs.fetch ('key').then (ok, fail);

// support for iOS suites (untested)
var suitePrefs = prefs.iosSuite ("suiteName");
suitePrefs.fetch (...);
suitePrefs.store (...);
```